# How to get gethostid behavior on windows 7?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, porting

I am porting a Linux code that uses `<unistd.h>`, specifically gethostid function, to Windows 7.

I need an unique number of 32 bits that I will use in my application. How can I obtain an unique number using API from Windows 7 in the same manner that I do on Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a very beautiful rabbit.

Comment: `long gethostid() { return 42; }` should work as well as the Linux version.

Comment: Haha, reminds me http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally implement this by returning the local IP address, for example by calling [`getaddrinfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @R.. I think you'll need to be clearer in your definition of *unique* for this comment to make sense. Unique in what domain? See [Open Group documents](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostid.html): "This volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 does not define the domain in which the return value is unique."

Comment: @R.. I also refer you to the [Linux man pages](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sethostid.2.html): "In the glibc implementation, if gethostid() cannot open the file containing
       the host ID, then it obtains the hostname using gethostname(2), passes that
       hostname to gethostbyname_r(3) in order to obtain the host's IPv4 address, and
       returns a value obtained by bit-twiddling the IPv4 address.  (This value may
       not be unique.)"

Comment: Well then I think coelhudo's comment to OP is the best answer... (Or Rob's)

Comment: @R.. This is just the nature of gethostid.